# need updated scoreboard PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I need to make a project for school where i have to be able to type in 2 teams(boxers) who are competing with each other and the team(boxer) who wins will rise up in rank on the scoreboard.

Somehow i can only manage to put in the number of wins which decides the rank of the player, but they need to fight each other and the outcome should update the scoreboard.

Its kinda important and deadline is nearing soon so any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welterweight Pound for Pound Reigning Champions</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welterweight Pound for Pound Reigning Champions</h1>
<form action="display.php" method= "post">
Name of fighter: <input type="text" name="name"><br />

Number of wins: <input type="text" name="wins"><br />

<input type="submit" name="verzenden" >
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['verzenden'])){

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("boksen", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO fighters (name, wins) VALUES            ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[wins]')";
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/display.php");
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: And what is your specific question? Besides, stop using `mysql_` functions, better use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: i need to be able to type in 

fighter 1 vs fighter 2 = result  via the form, the result should be updated in the scoreboard thats below it

Comment: `mysql_` functions have been deprecated for a long time, and removed entirely in PHP7. You should be migrating to `PDO` or `mysqli` a.s.a.p. otherwise you leave yourself vulnerable to security issues (your code is already very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks due to lack of parameterised queries, or indeed any input checking whatsoever) and also cannot upgrade to a newer PHP version until you change it. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for an intro to SQL injection and some examples of how to protect your data. It may only be a school project but you should get into good habits now.

Comment: "i need to be able to type in fighter 1 vs fighter 2 = result via the form, the result should be updated in the scoreboard thats below it". That's your requirement. But it's not a question. So...what's wrong with your code? What does it do now? ideally give an example using specific data and/or error messages as appropriate to demonstrate the problem. If you haven't written this feature at all yet, I'm afraid this isn't the forum for you. We fix bugs, we don't create brand new code.